# How to get disk name that contain specific partition

Tags: linux, bash

If i know that partition is for example /dev/sda1 how can i get disk name (/dev/sda in this case) that contain the partition?

The output should be only path to disk. (like '/dev/sda')

EDIT: It shouldn't be string manipulation

Comment: Are you looking for a naive string substitution approach or something more reliable/complex?

Comment: No because the partition can be like /dev/sda1 or /dev/mmcblk0p1 or other disk type. So this should work for every disk type.

Comment: @Snoop05 Is there a clear general rule that distinguishes between partitions and disks? If not, this is next to unsolvable. One or two examples are not a rule.

Comment: lsblk sees diference between them. In the TYPE column there are listed as "disk" and "part"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shell's built-in string chopping:

```
$ d=/dev/sda1
$ echo ${d%%[0-9]*}
/dev/sda
$ d=/dev/sda11212
$ echo ${d%%[0-9]*}
/dev/sda
```

This works for some of the disk names only. If there can be several digits in the name, it will chop everything after the first.

What is the exact specification to separate a disk name from a partition name?

Comment: As i stated in comment above, it has to also work for different disk types. Thats the reason why i not used string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` to get the disk. Because partitions are just increments of disk names, it's easy to perform:

`echo "/dev/sda1" | sed 's/[0-9]*//g'`

which produces the output `/dev/sda`

Another command you can use to obtain disk information is `lsblk`. Just typing it without args prints out all info pertaining to your disks and partitions.

Comment: This is 3rd commend that says it shouldnt be string manipulation because of different naming and numbering of different disk types.